# Nodejs Express app - Converting MongoDb Cursor to JSON

Tags: json, node.js, mongodb, cursor, bson

I'm running node v6.11.2, and my MongoDB is version 3.4.7.
I have a MongoDB with several users registered using passportjs and express-session for sessions. For rendering things like displaynames, user preferences, etc. i'm using EJS like this:

```
                    <p>
                        <strong>id</strong>: <%= user._id %><br>
                        <strong>email</strong>: <%= user.local.email %><br>
                        <strong>password</strong>: <%= user.local.password %><br>
                        <strong>Display name</strong>: <%= user.info.displayname %><br>
                        <strong>Subjects</strong>: <%= user.info.subjects %><br>
                    </p>
```

When rendering this ejs page, the GET request references the user that is in session like this:

```
user: req.user
```

This does not work for what i'm trying to do now, as it requires the user to be logged in. I would like to have a page where i can display the registered users, including their displaynames, some of their preferences etc (like public profiles).
I've tried (just for testing purposes) to slip the following line of code at the and of my app.js file:

```
console.log(db.users.find({}));
```

I expected this to return all the objects in my databse (and it does if i run it (without the console.log) in my mongo shell), but instead it returns a cursor like this:

```
Cursor {
  _readableState:
   ReadableState {
     objectMode: true,
     highWaterMark: 0,
     buffer: BufferList { head: null, tail: null, length: 0 },
     length: 0,
     pipes: null,
     pipesCount: 0,
     flowing: null,
     ended: false,
     endEmitted: false,
     reading: false,
     sync: true,
     needReadable: false,
     emittedReadable: false,
     readableListening: false,
     resumeScheduled: false,
     defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
     ranOut: false,
     awaitDrain: 0,
     readingMore: false,
     decoder: null,
     encoding: null },
  readable: true,
  domain: null,
  _events: {},
  _eventsCount: 0,
  _maxListeners: undefined,
  _opts: {},
  _get: [Function: thunk] }
```

How do i convert this to JSON?
Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it as follows: I added a few lines of code to my get request:

```
User.find({}).exec(function(err, users) {
            if (err) throw err;
            res.render('mentors.ejs', {
                'users': users
            })
```

I was then able to access the JSON as follows:

```
<% users.forEach(function (user) { %>     
    <p><%= user.info.displayname %></p>
        <p><%= user.info.subjects %></p>                                       
<% }) %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use `toArray()` method in the `db.users.find({}).toArray()`. This will return you the list of users and not the cursor.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I figured it out on my own. I guess i didn't look into the issue enough before i asked a question. I'll answer my own question.

Answer (score 0):

here is another solution ,try to implement async, await and convert to promise by using .toArray() then wait for first output by using Zero array index( [0]),

To understand more browse sample source in github:(nodejs-express-mongobd-graqhql)

[ https://github.com/barakaally/nodejs-express-graphql ]

sample code 
database connection(db.js)

```
const MongoClient = require("mongodb").MongoClient;
const keys = require("../keys");
class Db {
    constructor() { }

    static async con() {
        return (await MongoClient.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/", { useUnifiedTopology: true })).db("eshop");
    }


}

module.exports = Db;
```

Controller to use Db connection

```
const Db = require("../database/db");
class AuthController {
    /**
     * @typedef  {{loginInput:{email:String,password:String}}} LoginInput
     * @param {LoginInput} userInput
     * 
     */
    static async auth(userInput) {
        return (await (await Db.con()).collection("customers").find(userInput.loginInput).toArray())[0];
    }

}

module.exports = AuthController;
```